# is there an easy way to avoid creating all the folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Ok so I have this [site](http://posnation.com/).... with the url

```
http://posnation.com/
```

and there are alot of pages that i need to save the url structure for....like this

```
http://posnation.com/restaurant_pos
http://posnation.com/quickservice_pos
http://dev.posnation.com/retail_pos
```

ext....

The problem that i have now is that i want to save the same url for all these pages and I am looking for the best approach. The way its working now is its done with a code in miva and we are getting off miva.... I know I can create a folder named restaurant_pos or whatever the url is and create an index.php in there.This approach will work but the problem is I need to do this for 600 different pages and I dont feel like creating 600 folders in the best approach.

any ideas

Comment: are you saying you created all of those subfolders??

Comment: no what i am saying is that now in the public_html folder i have the index.php file and I need to save the same urls for all the old pages and rather then creating a folder for each directory is there a better way ....like maybe create one folder and then use some way to have the same url strurcture based on the filenames like restaurant_pos.php or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .htaccess to route all the requests to a single file, say index.php and do the serving from there based on the requested URL.

The following .htaccess file on the server root will route all the requests to your index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you should parse the $_REQUEST['route'] to identify which file you should serve. Here is an example that will serve a page based on the last element of the URL (ex: pos):

```
<?php

$parts = explode($_REQUEST['route']);

if ($parts[count($parts) - 1] == 'pos') {
    include "pages/pos.php";
}
```

Definitely you'll need to write your own logic, the above is just an example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the easiest way to do this is to create an .htaccess file that redirects all requests to `/index.php`.  In `/.index.php` you analyze the URL using probably `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and include the appropriate content.

Heres a sample htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In your `/.index.php` do something like ... (this is just a VERY simple example)

```
require 'pages/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '.php';
```

Now if someone goes to `http://posnation.com/restaurant_pos` `pages/restaurant_pos.php` will be included.

`pages/restaurant_pos.php` could include the header and footer too.

```
<?php require( HEADER_FILE ) ?>
restaurant_pos content
<?php require( FOOTER_FILE ) ?>
```