# how do I do to make "imaginary" folders at my website

Tags: html, database, url, dns, directory

Sorry, the start misundertanding.

What I want to do:

I have a domain: www.domain.com
all the pages like www.domain.com/page1, www.domain.com/page2 and etc.. are exactly the same but just changing de database.

how do I do to not create each html page with each folder?
or it's usual create each html page and folder?

but I need to have a specific url to each page, to share.

thks in advance!

Comment: are you using any server side languages ? like php ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to route everything through one index.php file.  There are several questions explaining this on SO.  For example this one seems pretty good.

[is there an easy way to avoid creating all the folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678831/is-there-an-easy-way-to-avoid-creating-all-the-folders)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server-side programming language with a routing engine, such as ASP.Net MVC.